# Get less optimal solution TSP

Tags: c

I am trying to do some tests on tsplib API, this API data files of cities coordinate, the best cost , and  tour with the best cost.

https://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/TSPLIB95/tsp/

I am using **lysses22** data file ,
My program

- read the coordinate of each city from the file ulysses22.tsp,
- generate the cost matrix,
- and compute the cost of the tour. Here is
  the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define NbrCities 22

double city_x[NbrCities], city_y[NbrCities];
float citymap[NbrCities*NbrCities];
int ids[NbrCities];


 float L2distance(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
    float x_d = pow(x1 - x2, 2);
    float y_d = pow(y1 - y2, 2);
    return sqrt(x_d + y_d); 
}


void costMatrix(float *citymap){
    for(int i=0; i<NbrCities; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<NbrCities; j++) {
            if(i!=j) {
                citymap[i*NbrCities+j] = L2distance(city_x[i], city_y[i], city_x[j], city_y[j]);
            } else {
                citymap[i*NbrCities+j] = 0;
            }
        }
     }
}


float cost(int* population, float* citymap) {

   float distance = 0;
   float population_cost;
    for (int j = 0; j < NbrCities-1; j++) {
        distance += citymap[ NbrCities*population[j] + population[j+1] ];
    }
        distance += citymap[ NbrCities*population[0] + population[NbrCities-1] ];

     return distance;
}


int main()
{

    FILE *myFile,*out;
    myFile = fopen("test.txt", "r");            
    out = fopen("out.txt", "w");

    int tour[]={1,14,13,12,7,6,15,5,11,9,10,19,20,21,16,3,2,17,0,4,18,8};

   myFile = fopen("test.txt", "r");
        for (int i = 0; i < NbrCities; i++)
            {
               fscanf(myFile,"%d %lf %lf",&ids[i],&city_x[i],&city_y[i]);  
            }

        costMatrix(citymap);



printf("  %f ",cost(tour,citymap));


 return 0;

}
```

The problem is that I've got the cost **153.66**

But in the web site  https://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/TSPLIB95/STSP.html  , the  best solution must be for lysses22 data file is: **7013**

I don't know why my result is less than the solution in the web site !
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: In the `cost` function, `citymap` is not indexed into correctly, missing the multiplication by `NbrCities`. Also the tour has 1..22 in it, not 0..21

Comment: Thanks , I just corrcted that but  I stil get less value: 153.66